# capture trafic on file over ssh

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I have an FW with a low storage space.
I can not do tcpdump on the fw because it does not keep me anything.
I want to perform a tcpdump on the FW via SSH and save the traffic on a computer that is on the network.

I managed to do it with this action:

```
"C: \ 2 \ plink.exe" -ssh admin@10.0.0.138 -pw admin -no-antispoof "tcpdump -s 0 -w - 'port 8080?" | "C: \ Program Files \ Wireshark \ Wireshark.exe" -i
```

The problem is that it activates my wireshark, and then I have to save the file.
Can I do this with Python?

I want to execute a script that will save the file alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the output with `> filename.pcap` instead of piping it to Wireshark.

```
"C: \ 2 \ plink.exe" -ssh admin@10.0.0.138 -pw admin -no-antispoof "tcpdump -s 0 -w - 'port 8080?" > filename.pcap
```

Comment: it's not working
Because if I add -W it's creates a file and leaves the screen blank
So the resulting file is also blank

Comment: Why would you use `-W` if you're writing to standard output with `-w -`?